# Add the numbers in list but keep the other elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I have this list of lists:

```
[["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]
```

I need to check for numbers in the sublists and add them, i.e. I want this output:

```
[["hari","cs",30],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing",0]]
```

I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: are the numbers always at the end of each list?

Comment: yes @StamKaly, you're right about the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate each sublist and sum the numbers (based on an `isinstance` check) and keep the not-numbers as is:

```
l = [["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]
newl = []
for subl in l:
    newsubl = []
    acc = 0
    for item in subl:
        if isinstance(item, (int, float)):
            acc += item
        else:
            newsubl.append(item)
    newsubl.append(acc)
    newl.append(newsubl)
print(newl)
# [['hari', 'cs', 30], ['krish', 'it', 10], ['yash', 'nothing', 0]]
```

In case you like generator functions this could be split into two functions:

```
l = [["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]

def sum_numbers(it):
    acc = 0
    for item in it:
        if isinstance(item, (int, float)):
            acc += item
        else:
            yield item
    yield acc

def process(it):
    for subl in it:
        yield list(sum_numbers(subl))

print(list(process(l)))
# [['hari', 'cs', 30], ['krish', 'it', 10], ['yash', 'nothing', 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d= [["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]

d1=[]               #result
for x in d:       
    m=[]            #buffer for non int
    z=0             # int sum temp var
    for i in x:
        if str(i).isdigit():   #check if element is an int
            z+=i
            #print z
        else:
            m.append(i)
    m.append(z)           #append sum
    d1.append(m)          #append it to result
print d1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = [["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]

new_list = []
for list_item in lists:
    new   = []
    count = 0
    for item in list_item:
        if type( item ) == int:
            count = count + item
        else:
            new.append( item )
    new.append( count )
    new_list.append( new )

print( new_list )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]
sums = [sum([x for x in _l if type(x) == int]) for _l in l]
without_ints = map(lambda _l: filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, _l, l))
out = [w_i + [s] for (s, w_i) in zip(sums, without_ints)]
>>> out
[['hari', 'cs', 30], ['krish', 'it', 10], ['yash', 'nothing', 0]]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

And here is the biggest one liner I've ever written..

Assuming the numbers are all at the end of each list, this should do the trick!

```
my_list = [["hari","cs",10,20],["krish","it",10],["yash","nothing"]]

new_list = [[element if type(element) != int else sum(inner_list[inner_list.index(element):]) for element in inner_list if type(inner_list[inner_list.index(element) - 1 if type(element) == int else 0]) != int] for inner_list in my_list]

print(new_list)  # [['hari', 'cs', 30], ['krish', 'it', 10], ['yash', 'nothing']]
```